# Checking for all points within specified distance of all line segments

Tags: open-source, computational-geometry

Given a set of points P and a set of segments S, is there a way to efficiently find all points within a specified distance d of any segment?  Without brute force comparison of order `O(|P||S|)`?

The Bentley-Ottman search for all intersections between a set of line segments runs in `O(n log n)`, and as this problem has a similar flavour, I wonder if similar performance is possible.

Bonus points for a permissive open source implementation in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Build a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) network on the points. Have each cell keep pointers to all of its neighbors. Than anything is possible.

1. given a point, find which cell it is in. Simple, draw a line from lower-left corner of network to the point, and starting from that corner cell, approach the point, thus finding the cell it is in.
2. Given a line, find all cells it crosses. Trivial.
3. Given a line and an offset distance, find all cells inside the corridor. Follows from 2.
4. etc.

The Voronoi network serves as a support structure for spatial  navigation and queries. All the operations are local, so linear complexity. *After* the diagram is built. :)